# How to get IP Address in Web Service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want to save IP address in my DB from Web Service. but I getting NULL value when I run my Web Service. Is there any way to get IP Address in Web Service?

Comment: Windows- or Web-Service?

Comment: Web Service. I have already declare in my question.

Comment: Have a look at your title. "How to get IP Address in Windows Service?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpRequest.Current.Request.UserHostAddress to retrieve the IP address of the user.

Hope this helps.